# Name of a symbol

Tags: notation

How is the symbol in the middle read and how to write it in latex
[image]

Comment: Try \$\mathfrak S\$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not know the symbol which is in the middle in the picture. If anyone can tell me what is symbol is. How to read it and how to write in latex

Answer (score 4):

You need to type:
`\usepackage{eufrak}` and then `\mathfrak{S}` between dollars `$ $`.
$$\mathfrak{S}$$

Hope it helps!

Edit: the package name is "eufrak", not "mathfrak", sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But how to read it

Comment: @InspireMaths: I would read it as `"ess"` ;-)